# Require() is not defined in electron - node js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using electron with node js. I have used require() already in two html files like this:

```
<script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
</script>
```

Now when I try to do the same thing in another html file in the same project, I get "ReferenceError: require is not defined" when the page loads. This other page is being shown in an iframe, but I'm not sure that would matter.

And for reference I have set nodeIntegration to true in main.js.

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  nodeIntegration: true
}
```

Why would it allow me to use require() in a script on two html files, but not this new one?

Comment: Possibly related: [require is not defined #10410](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10410).  They suggest using a [`<webview>`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) which in-turn suggests that `<webview>` is unstable or something and instead says to use a [`BrowserView`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view).

Answer (score 0):

As zero298 mentioned electron suggests using a webview, which I may move to in the future.

For now I ended up using window.parent to access the element that I needed in the parent window without using jQuery:

```
var but = window.parent.document.getElementById('saveAction');
```